# Can i use KXML framework?

Tags: android, frameworks, kxml

Can i use KXML framework for android application?

Comment: Do you mean KML? (As in the mapping markup used with Google Maps / Google Earth). Please be more descriptive about what you're hoping to do with said framework.

Comment: Hi KXML is used for xml parser. see this link http://www.devx.com/xml/Article/11773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports KXML. I used KXML for android application. Its working fine.